# cookie named "__cfduid" has a domain that starts with a dot

Tags: java, spring-boot, reactive

i'm trying to make an http post call fo a url
i'm using java springboot version 2.2.0
i try to map the cookies i get from the response.
one of the cookies named "__cfduid" contains a domain that starts with a dot.
as from version 2.2.0, the class ResponseCookie forbides a dot as the first char of the domain.
it throws an IllegalArgumentException, "Invalid first/las char in cookie domain"
is there a way to bypass this check beside downgrade to version 2.1.9?
my code looks like this:

```
    webClient = Webclient
    .builder()
    .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient)
    .baseUrl(myUrl)
    .build();

    webClient
     .post()
     .uri(url)
     .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
     .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
     .body(Mono.just(myObject), MyObject.class)
     .exchange()
     .subscribe(
        response -> {
           for (key: response.cookies().keySet()){
              // the exception occurs at 
              // response.cookies
           }
     });
```